# how to write laravel model having with multi conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, having

We can write orwhere clause like:

```
$model::select('*')->where(function($query {
   $query->orWhere()
         ->orWhere();
})
```

How can I write orhaving clause below not with raw way:

```
$model::havingRaw('(count > 10 and count <20) or (xxx and xxx)')
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet to nest `having` clauses. You have to use raw SQL.

This feature has been suggested: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/999

Answer (score 1):

You can use snippet code

```
$query->orHaving('count', '>', 10)->orHaving('count', '<', 20);
```

Comment: thx! but orHaving->orHaving is just like sql having xxx or xxxx; but i wanna like sql having (xxx and xxx)  or (xxx and xxx)